# Как проверить наличие строки в массиве строк?

Tags: c++, linux, массивы, строки

Имеется код C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // код
    string massive_strok[8] { stroka1, ... };
// строки все записаны в виде переменных (в т ч через peremennaya.c_str()).
    string user_input;
    cin >> user_input;
    if (user_input in massive_strok) {
    // код
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Как проверить наличие строки в массиве строк (код выше не помог).? Я встречал такое решение:

```
if (user_input in str(massive_strok))
```

Но мне и оно не помогло. И да, я не могу проинициализировать массив как `char[] []`, поскольку строки имеют различные длины. **Используемая ОС - Linux/Unix**.

Comment: Цикл по строкам в массиве, сравнивая каждую с образцом. Обнаружилась — дальше можно не проверять...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо

```
if (user_input in massive_strok) {
```

Что-то вроде

```
bool found = false;
for(auto s: massive_strok) if (s == user_input) { found = true; break; }

if (found) {
```

И еще — имеет смысл учить язык, а не придумывать несуществующие в нем конструкции...

Answer (score 0):

Можно пользоваться дарами стандартной библиотеки и использовать функции [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), [`begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) и [`end`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end):

```
if (find(begin(massive_strok), end(massive_strok), user_input) != end(massive_strok))
{
    // code
}
```